# Unsafe compareAndSwapInt vs synchronize

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, unsafe

I found that almost all high level synchronization abstractions(like Semaphore, CountDownLatch, Exchanger from java.util.concurrent) and concurrent collections are using methods from Unsafe(like compareAndSwapInt method) to define critical section. In the same time I expected that synchronize block or method will be used for this purpose.
Could you explain is the Unsafe methods(I mean only methods that could atomically set a value) more efficient than synchronize and why it is so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `synchronised` is more efficient if you expect to be waiting a long time (e.g. milli-seconds) as the thread can fall asleep and release the CPU to do other work.

Using `compareAndSwap` is more efficient if you expect the operation to happen quite quickly.  This is because it is a simple machine code instruction and take as little as 10 ns. However if a resources is heavily contented this instruction must busy wait and if it cannot obtain the value it needs, it can consume the CPU busily until it does.

If you use off heap memory, you can control the layout of the data being shared and avoid false sharing (where the same cache line is being updated by more than one CPU).  This is important when you have multiple values you might want to update independently. e.g. for a ring buffer.

Note that the internal implementation of a typical JVM (e.g., hotspot) will often used the compare-and-swap hardware instruction as *part* of the `synchronized` implementation if such an instruction is available (e.g,. x86), while the other common alternative is [LL/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional) (e.g., POWER, ARM). A typical strategy to for the fast path to use compare-and-swap (or equivalent) to attempt to obtain the lock if it is free, followed possibly by a short [spin-loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) and finally if that fails falling back to an OS-level blocking primitive (e.g., [futex](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html), [Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655(VS.85).aspx)). The details go far beyond this and include techniques such as [biased locking](https://blogs.oracle.com/dave/biased-locking-in-hotspot) and are ultimately implementation dependent.

Comment: Can you elaborate on last para? Little confusion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47851595/3317808)

Comment: Which JVM does the last paragraph refer to?

Comment: I edited it a bit to clarify it in the context of the confusion in the other thread. I think the key is that Peter is referring to the hardware CAS instruction (or similar) in the last paragraph, not any Java language-level `compareAndSwap` method or algorithm, which led to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is not fulfilling. The approach is: A mutex (synchronization) is not necessary because the only one operation does the work (all what is to do in mutex), and this only one operation is not able to interrupt. But that is the half answer, because in a multicore system another CPU can write to the same memory location. For that reason the compareAndSwap machine code instruction reads and writes not only in the cache, it reads and writes to real memory. That needs a little more access time to the RAM. The CompareAndSwap machine code operation checks whether the RAM content is changed in comparison to the before read value, only then the new value is stored. If I have more time, I write an example here.

Effective, the compareAndSwap access is faster than a lock and unlock anytime. But it can only be used if only exact one memory location have to be changend in the access. If more as one memory locations should be commonly changed (should be always consistente together), the compareAndSwap CANNOT be used, only synchronzed can be used. In the answer above it was written, compareAndSwap is often used to implement the synchronized operation. That is correct, because the singular synchronized (get mutex) and end-synchronized (release mutex) need only exact one atomic instruction, inside the task scheduler. Hence atomic access is the base of all. But between synchronized{ .... } the scheduler knows that a thread switch is guarded.

This program approach is valid not only for Java, for C/++ (and maybe other languages - ) it is also important and able to use.