# Mutual exclusion - How synchronized works?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

As mentioned in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34944369/3317808), `synchronized` is implemented using *compareAndSwap*, which is non-blocking algorithm.

1. On `synchronized` without using `wait()`, Does a thread state set to `BLOCKED`?
2. Does a thread in `BLOCKED` & `WAITING` state consume CPU cycles?

Comment: You can't rely on a SO answer as an authoritative statement about the implementation of the JVM. He doesn't even mention which JVM he is referring to. You would need to cite an official Sun/Oracle document, and even then it's only a statement about the Sun/Oracle JVM.

Answer (score 5):

> As mentioned in answer, synchronized is implemented using compareAndSwap, which is non-blocking algorithm.

I think you are misreading that answer. `synchronized` is certainly not implemented with the Java-level `compareAndSwap` call. It will be implemented in native code by the interpreter and JIT in your JVM. Under the covers it *might* use the compare-and-swap instruction, or it may use something else (atomic test-and-set and atomic exchange are also common - and some platforms don't even have a CAS primitive).

This is definitely not a "non-blocking algorithm" - by definition `synchronized` implements a type of critical section which implies *blocking* if a second thread tries to enter the critical section while another thread is inside it.

> 1) On synchronized without using wait(), Does a thread state set to BLOCKED?

Yes, if a thread is waiting to enter a `synchronized` section, its state is set to `BLOCKED`.

> 2) Does a thread in BLOCKED & WAITING state consume CPU cycles?

Generally no, at least not in an ongoing manner. There is a CPU cost associated with entering and exiting the state<sup>1</sup>, but once the thread is blocked it is generally held in a non-runnable state until it is awoken when the monitor becomes free, and doesn't use CPU resources during that time.

---

<sup>1</sup> Which is exactly why good implementations will generally "spin" a bit before going to sleep, in case the critical section is short and the holding thread may soon exit - spinning in this case avoids the 1000+ cycle overhead of making the transition to sleep (which involves the OS, etc).

Comment: no? But Peter says in that answer, *synchronized is implemented using a compareAndSwap *

Comment: @overexchange that's not what Peter said, you omitted "... and much more besides". Synchronized is *not* busy-looping.

Comment: @overexchange - Peter probably means that is common for the _underlying JVM_ to implement the _fast-path_ for `synchronized` with the same hardware instruction that underlies `compareAndSwap` (because that's typically how locks are implemented, period). It doesn't mean there is necessarily a compare-and-swap going on (some platforms don't ever offer that functionality). He's basically saying if you implement you can implement your own "spinlock" using `compareAndSwap` and it might use the same hardware instruction to implement that part as `synchronized`.

Comment: ... but I don't know where you got that `compareAndSwap` (hereafter "CAS") is non-blocking: any time you use CAS to spin on a lock-type variable that will be set by another thread only when some condition is met, you have blocking (your thread is blocked, just burning CPU). That's how a spinlock works, but this is certainly "blocking". Usually when you'll block for a long time you want to make the thread non-runnable, which requires the OS to get involved, but then lets you block without using CPU.

Comment: I got from [here](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/cs892/2017-PDFs/L1-Java-synchronizers-pt2.pdf#page=6). It is a spin lock implementation of `lock()`. `lock()` is looping, it requires CPU cycles.

Comment: @overexchange - right, the CAS itself is "a lock-free primitive" in that it either succeeds or fails in a bounded amount of time, but if you put it in a loop (like that first slide) then you have a spin-lock and that is blocking. Non-blocking or lock-free basically mean "if all the thread threads in the process were suspended, will I make forward progress?". Clearly if one thread holds the lock gets suspended a second thread will _never_ get the lock even if using CAS to spin-loop since the lock variable will never become `0` (in the example in those slides).

Comment: Am saying that, for CAS to spin-loop, it requires CPU cycles.

Comment: Yes, of course. No one implied otherwise. @overexchange

Comment: If CAS is spin-looping and `synchronised` is implemented using CAS, then,what is the answer to question 2).

Comment: @overexchange "CAS" is not "spin looping". CAS is just a hardware instruction that can be used to do a compare-and-swap operation. You can _use it to implement a spin-loop_, of course. `synchronized` is certainly not implemented **just** just a CAS spin-loop. There will be an initial CAS attempt to get the lock, if that fails it may spin for a certain number of iterations (which may be adaptive based on past behavior for that monitor) and if the lock is not obtained during that period, it will make itself non-runnable until the lock is available, at which point it stops using CPU.

Comment: I'm not sure if the thread state (e.g., as reported by `jstack`) is set to `BLOCKED` before the spin loop, or after the spin loop and before sleeping (you can check the source), but the difference is minor since the spin period is probably a few microseconds or less. The vast majority of threads that you see as `BLOCKED` are typically sleeping and not using CPU.

Comment: After making thread itself non-runnable, how does thread know, when to come out of non-runnable state? to obtain the lock

Comment: It is the responsibility of the thread leaving the lock to notify the waiting threads (which is done with the help of the OS, e.g., `futex` on Linux or the events & `WaitForObject` stuff on Windows). The usual pattern is that a lock can have 3 states: (1) unlocked (2) locked, no waiters and (3) locked with 1+ waiters. If a thread can't get the lock blocks, it ensures the state is set to (3). On exit from the critical section, the thread giving up the lock will check if it is state (3) and if so also do a  "notify/wake" operation to wake one or more sleeping threads.

Comment: If the state is (2) is can avoid that (since it is expensive, and the uncontended lock acquire/release path is very important to performance). Note that when a thread is "spinning" on the lock, it is state (2) not state (3). @overexchange

Comment: If `synchronized` internally perform 'notify/wake' operation to wake sleeping threads then why java provide `obj.wait()` & `obj.notify()`? Is that for co-ordination between threads, which is different from entering/leaving critical section?

Comment: @overexchange - if you have a totally new question like this one, create a separate Q&A, don't use comments. The short answer though is that `notify()` and `wait()` provide additional useful semantics to java programs (similar to what a condition variable offers on POSIX systems) - that's why the "lock" associated with Java objects is called a _monitor_ and not just a plain "critical section". The semantics of those calls are quite different than plain critical section use. I'm not sure why you'd consider it unusual that they are implemented with the same underlying OS primitives though.

Comment: Can I say that `synchronized` internally does not use *spin-lock* or *sleep-lock*, but *hybrid-lock*?

Comment: @overexchange - Ask a new question.  Like BeeOnRope advised you.

Comment: @over - if you ask a new question link it here and I'll be happy to have a look.